# Practical/experimental difference between (quantum) Heisenberg and (classical) Ising model

Tags: condensed-matter, quantum-spin, ising-model, spin-models

I have read a few discussions about the difference between the Heisenberg model (using quantum spin operators) and Ising model (with spins $\pm 1$), notably [this one](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/280181/what-new-features-does-the-heisenberg-model-have-compared-to-the-ising-model) or [this Quora post](https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-advantages-of-the-Heisenberg-model-over-the-Ising-model).

All the responses seem to be of theoretical nature, highlighting, e.g., the difference in symmetry or the Mermin-Wagner theorem stating the Heisenberg model does have a phase transition at $d\leq 2$.

I am interested in practical aspects. Imagine I want to simulate some real material (let us consider a $3d$ lattice only). Even an undergraduate can write and run a Monte Carlo code simulating the Ising model a few hours. On the other hand, the Heisenberg model involves a true effort. Writing it requires immense knowledge, intuition and skill (constructing the Hamiltonian and total spin operators and computing the expectation values), and running it demands powerful computers even for a fairly low number of atoms and approximation schemes (see [this review of methods](https://arxiv.org/abs/1101.3281)).

Given the amount of effort, what is the justification for using the quantum Heisenberg model? What new *vital* features observed in experiment does it provide? If any, can they not be reproduced by the Ising model with vectorised but classical 3D spins, $-J \sum_{\langle ij\rangle} \mathbf S_i \cdot \mathbf S_j$?

Edit: To clarify that what I am trying to figure out is different from [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/280181/what-new-features-does-the-heisenberg-model-have-compared-to-the-ising-model), I am not interested in theoretical *features*, but in practical/experimental results in three dimensions. That is, to what extent do Heisenberg/Ising models correctly predict:

- critical exponents of magnetisation, heat capacity and susceptibility,
- collective excitations (can these be captured by 3d Ising model?),

for a range of ferromagnetic materials, and where do they fail?

Comment: Superpositions, for one.

Comment: @probably_someone can you elaborate?

Comment: Your question sounds misleading: From a practical point of view, you would use the model which best captures the real physics of your system, rather than the one which is simplest to simulate.  Also, your claim that the Heisenberg model is hard to simulate is unjustified, at least for bipartite lattices where there are very good algorithms which are not too hard to code.  (Admittedly, harder than the Ising model, but still pretty simple.)  So I don't see how your "amount of effort" argument makes sense, except for, say, a homework assignment.

Comment: BTW, I'd say that symmetry breaking (->Mermin-Wagner) IS a "vital feature".  If it isn't, what would be a "vital feature" in your opinion?  Other "vital features" might be the magnetization curve, or critical exponents, or the value of the magnetization.  Are these "vital features" in your opinion?  If not, what would be?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What new features does the Heisenberg Model have compared to the Ising Model?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/280181/what-new-features-does-the-heisenberg-model-have-compared-to-the-ising-model)   (I think it needs to be made more clear *what* exactly would be a satisfactory answer not covered by this question and its answers.)

Comment: @NorbertSchuch Are there in practice any materials that are ferromagnetic in 3d but not in 2d, assuming can be fabricated in 2d at all? If not, then Mermin-Wagner is not a vital feature of real life. I have edited the question to make it clear what I consider important. Also, I think I explained sufficiently that my question is not a duplicate, as I am interested in comparison with real materials. Finally, I would welcome any tutorial that would (with reasonable effort) teach me to code the Heisenberg model, if you know any. So far, I have not seen one.

Comment: @petervanya I'm not sure what "same material" in different dimensions even means.  I mean, I know what the same *model* is, but the same *material* -- could you give me some examples where you would call something the "same material" despite different dimensionality?

Comment: @NorbertSchuch Graphene is the best example of a 2d material. Its 3d equivalent is graphite. In general, see [this wiki entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-dimensional_materials).

Comment: Well, I guess we can leave that aside - as far as I understand it isn't directly relevant to your question.

Comment: Ok, simple answer: The low-temperature excitation spectrum of the Heisenberg and Ising model (ferromagnet) are fundamentally different.  I'm sure there's neutron scattering data on that out there.  And I'm not even sure how you would model the neutron scattering off spin 1/2 particles with a classical vector model.  Would this be satisfactory?

Comment: Regarding a Heisenberg model, a colleague who is a MC expert told me once that writing an SSE code from scratch (which can do Heisenberg) would take him 3 hours. (Or maybe it was 1/2 hour, not sure any more.)  In any case, no need to use quantum numbers unless you want to push the method.

Comment: Random source: Fig. 1 of http://www.bourbaphy.fr/maillet.pdf.  I'd say the agreement is compelling.

Comment: Yes, I think I agree that I cannot imagine how to do neutron scattering on classical vector models. Thanks for the link, I agree that agreement shown in Fig. 1 is impressive. However, as I mentioned, what I am after is a systematic evaluation across a range of materials, not just one. This sort of testing is often done with numerical methods. But I am starting to think that this is probably an open question.